# Harms vs. could harm

Tags: meaning, sentence-choice, redundancy

> On the other hand, there are a lot of cases where X **could harm** Y or at least gives nothing.

> On the other hand, there are a lot of cases where X **harms** Y or at least gives nothing.

Which sentence is more accurate? I see that people often prefer the former version, but isn't it better to use the latter?

"Could" seems redundant to me in such a context. When we use "could", we are considering both "branches": with and without making harm. But we already left out "harmless" cases when we said "There are a lot of..." Yes, there are a lot of them, but we haven't said that they are the only ones.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between *This statement **is** true* and *This statement **could be** true*? In some contexts, people use ***could be*** when they really mean ***is*** to "soften" an assertion, but I'm sure something similar occurs in *every* natural language. And obviously we here have no idea whether your specific context is one where there really is some degree of uncertainty regarding the possible harmful effects of X on Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not redundant.

Let us suppose that there is a spring in the desert that is poisonous owing to the concentration of arsenic in the ground and so in the water.  A trail goes by it.  Anyone who walks by **could** be harmed (by drinking the water), but that does not mean that most people **are**.